# How can a chrome extension add a floating bar at the bottom of pages?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am creating a chrome extension that needs to inject a floating element (i.e `position:fixed`)
at the bottom of pages . My requirements are:

- I need to access elements inside it from a content script.
  This is because I attach events to buttons so the user can perform actions on the current tab from the floating bar.
- I want it's styles to remain as independent from styles of the current page.

So far I have tryed three solutions and came up with nothing.

1. **content script injecting a fixed html element**.
   The problem with this solution is that the style of the page and the style of my element would effect each other thus resulting in web pages affecting the style of my element an vice versa.
2. **content script injecting an iframe**.
   The problem here was it is impossible to access elements inside the iframe from the content script that created the iframe and on the other hand chrome extensions do not allow running content scripts inside a dynamically injected iframes (even when using `all_frames: true`).
3. **Extending the Devtool panel**
   This did not fit my needs since I needed my panel to show on every page. e.g the user can preform an action that opens several tabs and have all of them have my element. in the devtool panel my user would then have to open devtoold in all tabs manually.

Please advise.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

As Sudarshan commented, an iframe is the best practice here.

in order to run a script within the iframe I simply included the iframe.html and script.js within my plugin. In my content script I got the iframe with [`chrome.extension.getURL('iframe.html')`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html) (only background script can access this API so I used [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)) the script was included as a relative script tag within the iframe like so: `<script src="script.js"></script>`

The surprising part for me was that although script.js was not included in the manifest, It can still access chrome api and, more importantly in my case, send messages to the background script.

Comment: -1 for saying the post above was the way to go but accepting your own comment as the correct solution

Answer (score 23):

Suggestions for 3 approaches

## Content script injecting a fixed html element

Yes, the styles if specified are too generic in web pages

**Ex:**

```
div { 
   border:none;
}
```

does effect content script(s) elements even you assign rare combination of id(s) and classes to css, Solution is to specify (or) override all styles using css which is very cumbersome

**Ex:** Over ride every style which is error prone and cumbersome.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

## Content script injecting an iframe.

I suggest this is best approach , regarding your concern on script injection on dynamic iframes; Yes it is possible to inject script to dynamic generated iframes

### Sample Implementation

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Iframe",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "myscript.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "anotherscript.js"
            ],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

#### myscript.js

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://allofrgb.blogspot.in/");
iframe.setAttribute("style", "border:none; width:150px; height:30px");
iframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

#### anotherscript.js

```
iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (iframe in iframes){
    console.log(iframes[iframe].src);
}
console.log("In another Script");
```

If you observe console logged messages you observe messages are logged twice (`document` log + `iframe` log + `[any number of optional iframes in pages]*`)

`anotherscript.js` which runs during `document idle` states does execute in dynamic generated iframe, how ever you can re-run content script through [chrome.tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) any time.

## Extending the Devtool panel

You have clearly identified problems, so eliminating it as an alternative.

Comment: Injecting an iframe turned out to be the best practice here. unfortunately I could not get this solution working. In the above example i believe what is happening is the content script with all_frames (anotherscript.js) simply run in the tab containing the iframe, as it should, just like another content script.
It did not however run again in the dynamically injected iframe. so it could access the iframe element itself, but not elements inside it.

Comment: @mooli:It can access elements inside it, can you show code where it did not work, i have thoroughly tested this.

Comment: I gave this a try, and it works. Unfortunately, in my case I set the src attribute to chrome.runtime.getURL('/some/path'), and in that case anotherscript.js does not get injected, probably because it is a chrome extension url itself. A bit unfortunate, because I was doing this dance to get access to the chrome sendMessage api, not to get access to the iframe contents dom.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP is asking how to inject his own crafted page from within the extension onto every page at the bottom.  This code doesn't answer the question, and also many other sites refuse to let you load them into an iframe, so nothing is loaded.  Furthermore, you can't specify a local page directly in a content script.  So as the OP's answer suggests, you must load iframe html in a background script and pass a message to the content script to load into the iframe.  Either that or code the entire html page inside the content script, but that may be a nightmare to maintain.