# Message Listener in iFrame Created by Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've created a chrome extension that uses a content script to create a floating iFrame in the page, which in turn also loads another content script.

[Per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290428/how-can-a-chrome-extension-add-a-floating-bar-at-the-bottom-of-pages), this appears to best way to insulate my content from CSS in the actual page.

The content script in my iFrame has a listener (i.e. chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener) for messages created by the extension.

This works *most of the time*.

What appears to be happening is that the message is being sent by the extension before my iFrame has fully loaded, and the listener has had a change to be setup yet.

I'm sending the message from the background script in a callback function once my original content script is complete, but this doesn't guarantee the listener in the iFrame is available yet.

If I throw in an arbitrary delay before sending the message (i.e. a half second), it appears to work, but this is a pretty ugly hack.

Is there a better way to setup my listener in the iFrame?

Here's my code:

```
//background script
window.addEventListener("load", chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(onCompleted, { urls: ['http://acme.com/*'], types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame']});, false);

function onCompleted(details) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {file: "page_content_script.js"}, function() {chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab_id, {url: details.url});});
}

//page_content_script.js
my_iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
my_div = document.createElement("div");
my_iframe.id = "my_iframe";
my_div.id = "my_div";
//my_div.style = "style div as needed here to make it appear a dialog"
my_iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL('iframe_content.html');
my_div.appendChild(my_iframe);
document.body.appendChild(my_div)


//iframe content
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>      
<script src="iframe_content_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
some stuff here
</body>

//iframe_content_script.js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
console.log('message received!');
}
```

Comment: Bind the listener at the background/event page, and let the content script send the message.

Comment: Rob - sorry if I'm a bit confused. How can I bind the listener in my background my page without knowing when my iFrame has actually loaded?

Comment: After binding an event listener, all future messages will trigger the event listener. So, you don't even have to know when the iframe is loaded.

Comment: Huh, webRequest? Just bind an event using `chrome.runtime.onMessage,addListener( ... )` and send the message from a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Comment: If you want to add code, please edit your question to include it. It's currently unreadable (delete the comments to clean up). PS. I've answered your last question in my previous comment.

Comment: How do I setup the listener the background page, but have it execute in the iFrame?

Comment: Please read the documentation for [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) and [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html). They contain plenty of examples on setting up the events.

Comment: I've definitely read the docs. I think I'm confused because I'm not sure how I can guarantee my listener will be setup before the message from the background page is sent.

Comment: The background page is run before anything else. After you've declared that you're listening to the `onMessage` event, all future `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` calls will be received by the listener you've bound. Got it?

Comment: Sorta (sorry for being a bit lost here). Maybe I'm confused how to setup the listener in the background, but have it be able to access variables/functions declared in the iFrame script.