# Append iframe before body loads

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension of a button that I want to have loaded on the page before the body of the page loads. I found a solution that might work by having the  [content script inject an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290428/how-can-a-chrome-extension-add-a-floating-bar-at-the-bottom-of-pages). However, as I have the content script set to `"run_at": "document_start"` instead of `"run_at": "document_end"`as in the example, when I try to append this iframe by; `document.body.appendChild(iframe);`, I'm getting an error as the body is null still. Does anyone know how to an iframe before the body is loaded?

Comment: That's impossible

Comment: Append it to document.documentElement

Comment: It's not actually clear why you want to load it before the body, but there's also an option to wait for the exact moment `body` gets appended by utilizing the deprecated synchronous DOM mutation events, then append the iframe as the first element to the body. And if the timing is not that important you can use the asynchronous MutationObserver that will run a tad later when the body may have a few elements.

Comment: @wOxxOm This was the closest I could get to what I wanted! +1